# Binding event to class inside a specific id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, events, jquery

I have 3 elements with the same structure

```
<div id="Chatbox1">
    <div class="chatboxhead">            
        <div class="chatboxoptions">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ToggleChatBoxGrowth" title="Minimize chat box">-</a>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

the only difference is that each one of them has a different ID (Chatbox1, Chatbox2, Chatbox3).

I tried to bind 'Click' event to `.ToggleChatBoxGrowth` class for each one:

```
$('#chatbox_' + id + ' > .chatboxhead > .chatboxoptions > .ToggleChatBoxGrowth').click(function ()
    {
        ChatBox.ToggleChatBoxGrowth(id);
    });
```

but the problem is that all of them are bound by the same click event.
So when I click on `ChatBox1` one I'm getting click event with `id = ChatBox3`

Can you help?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Exactly which class here needs to have the 'Click' event ?

Comment: @RijuMahna .ToggleChatBoxGrowth class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bind the click even to `ToggleChatBoxGrowth` using the class selector, then traverse up the DOM to receive the parents Id.

```
$(".ToggleChatBoxGrowth").click(function(){
   var parentId = $(this).parents(".chatboxhead").parent().attr("id");
   ChatBox.ToggleChatBoxGrowth(parentId);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6C2aQ/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.ToggleChatBoxGrowth', '[id^="chatbox_"]').on('click', function() {
  ChatBox.ToggleChatBoxGrowth( $(this).closest('[id^="chatbox_"]').attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MSxhy/

```
ChatBox.ToggleChatBoxGrowth($(this).parents('[id="Chatbox'+id+'"]').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

By your description it appears your are using a loop to bind the events. Is this right?
If so the "id" will have the value of the last iteration of your loop. If you want to retain it you can do it through closures

```
while(id<3){
  (function(){
      var localId = id;
      $('#chatbox_' + id+ ' > .chatboxhead > .chatboxoptions > .ToggleChatBoxGrowth').click(function ()
       {
          ChatBox.ToggleChatBoxGrowth(localId);
       });
   })();
   id++;
}
```